# Error in geting Epoch Time in python3

Tags: python-3.x, epoch

I am trying to write a simple sntp client for printing time.when I try to assign TIME1970 = 2208988800L ,it gives an error saying invalid syntax.I am running program on python3 plus windows environment 64 bit.

Comment: The SyntaxError message will also show a little `^` symbol pointing to the particular character in the statement `TIME1970 = 2208988800L` which is causing the error. Please post the entire error statement as this might provide an extra clue.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax for long int literals is no longer valid in python 3. All integers are now longs by default.

Comment: Ok I removed L from that statement Now its saying str doesn't support buffer interface

Comment: That error cannot come from the line you posted. Please post the complete code and error trace for all questions here.

Comment: from socket import *
import struct
import sys
import time

TIME1970=2208988800

client = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
data = '\x1b' + 47 * '\0'
client.sendto( data, ( sys.argv[1], 123 ))
data, address = client.recvfrom( 1024 )
if data:
    print ('Response received from:', address)
    t = struct.unpack( '!12I', data )[10]
    t -= TIME1970
    print ('\tTime=%s' % time.ctime(t))

Comment: That's unreadable and incomplete. Best bet is probably to start a new question with proper formatting and complete information. Or just edit it into this question.